# Samba 3.x for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: samba, 14.04

Is there a samba 3 package for Ubuntu 14.04?  Thus far I have not come across any such thing, so I suppose the better question is should I just compile samba 3 from source?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 14.04 ships with Samba 4.x only. If you want Samba 3.x, you will need to find a third party repository (eg. a PPA) or compile from source.

Alternatively, if you want to use older versions of software then you can stick to an older Ubuntu release. For example, 12.04 will be supported until April 2017.